# correct ordering of asymptotic growth

Tags: complexity-theory

Hello I have solved this problem but I doubt if my answer is correct or not.

Write the following functions in a correct ordering of asymptotic
growth, starting with the slowest growing.

```
n^2logn , n^(0.0001) , (logn)^(10000) , n(logn)^2 , 10^100 , nsqrt(n)logn , 2^n , n^(logn)
```

and this is my answer:

```
10^100 < n^(0.0001) < n(logn)^2 < nsqrt(n)logn < (logn)^(10000) < n^2logn < 2^n < n^(logn)
```

Is my answer correct??

Comment: You could put a value for *n* and find out, I think.

Comment: The easiest way to compare two functions' (let's say f and g) would be to calculate f(n) / g(n) when n goes to infinity. To simplify this, someone made a [widget on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=57ad04c0f04cc92e742205985c18023e) that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(logn)^c` grows asymptotically slower than `n^d` for any constants `c` and `d>0`, so `(logn)^(10000)` should be placed after `10^100`.

`n^(logn)` is the same as `e^((logn)^2)` (or `2^((logn)^2)` depending on the base you assume for `log`), which is (for similar reason) asymptotically dominated by `2^n`.

Otherwise looks correct, although the way you wrote the terms may cause ambiguities in interpretation.